# Build failing because of multiple solution files

Tags: bitbucket, appharbor

My Appharbor builds are failing with this error message:

Couldn't pick a single solution file to build. Found: \SolutionName.sln and \BitBucketUserName-BitBucketRepositoryName-ccbc51ee8378\SolutionName.sln

The ccbc51ee8378 is the repository commit id.  (I replaced the other values with tokens)

I only have a single solution, and when I look at the files on my machine and the source within BitBucket, I only see the single solution file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, you should try downloading the source tarball and inspect it's contents (this is what AppHarbor gets). You can retrieve it by hitting `src -> get source`.

Comment: The problem happened when I added a bunch of directories and static file content.  I think the length of the directory and file names was too long since some of the files had truncated names.  When I tried to unpack the tarball, about 10 of the files caused errors and I noticed the truncation.  I've since removed the files from my solution and it builds fine.  Thank you for the direction.